# How could i adjust the direction of section number and section name?

Tags: titlesec

In Default Settings , `LaTeX` let the section name and section number both are bottom align, like this: 
[image]

now I want them use the "center align" like this:

[image]

I try to use the `titlesec` package to customize it, but it was not helpful.

Sorry for my poor English. :*>

Comment: Default Settings of what?

Comment: try`\raisebox{<length>}[0pt][0pt]{1}` with negative length you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `titlesec` and a simple `\raisebox`, as pointed by @touhami, with a small adjustment to have the section number fully cenntred:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, calc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}{\raisebox{-0.5\height + 0.5ex}{\scalebox{2.5}[3]{\color{IndianRed3}\thesection}}}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{example}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what i want.

Comment: think you so much :>